# What is the effect of a varying Vcc on the output pin of an IC?

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, output, bypass-capacitor

I'm designing a circuit with [this transceiver](http://www.promelec.ru/pdf/XTR_434(full).pdf). But I was wondering what the effect would be of an voltage source without a bypass capacitor, so with a possible varying Vcc. Would this affect the voltage at the output pin?

Answer (score 4):

First let's put it on the table that the Vcc pins of IC chips really need to have local bypass capacitors to GND or the return  pin of the IC for those that may use a different name such as Vss.

If the Vcc of the IC varies it will generally have a direct impact on the high level output level of a digital IC. To a lesser degree it will also have an effect on how well the output pin can drive to a low level due to fact that the bias to the pulling down transistor comes from the Vcc supply.

For linear circuits, lets use op-amps for this discussion, the output voltage is generally not operating at the rails *(if it was it would act more like the digital chip)* and is set by feedback resistors and the nature of the input signal and biasing. For these applications you would really hope that variation of the supply voltage, within reasonable limits, would have no impact on the output voltage. In real life it will have some impact and so to quantify this effect the data sheet of a part will specify a "power supply rejection ratio" that specified how much the output is affected.

Answer (score 1):

You assume that no supply decoupling would affect the output voltage of this module. But does that matter ? The output is digital so as long as a zero and a one can be detected, it will make no difference.

However, there are some analog circuits in this module that are far more sensitive to supply variations. The result of omitting the supply decoupling can be from making no difference (the circuits in the module have a very high supply rejection, there is on board supply regulation, there are bypass caps already), to the module does not work AT ALL. And anything in between ! So performance could be compromised as in less sensitivity, emission of spurious signals etc.

So that's why in a good design we spend some cents and place proper supply decoupling so that at least we did our best to decouple the supply as is expected.

Comment: This is terrible advice. Of course supply decoupling on digital ICs matters! Not having it will create noise on both the power and signal lines, and may lead to odd failures from the IC in question or anything connected to it.

Comment: You didn't read it properly, the question stated that supply ripple would change the output voltage. I was commenting about that statement, that the output voltage changes due to supply ripple. That would not matter as long as the rest of the circuit remains functional. The question does not mention that although it is far more relevant. I did not state anywhere that supply decoupling on digital circuits does not matter because it does like it does for analog circuits.

Comment: "Changes due to supply ripple" are called _noise_. And even that aside, yes it does matter, because logic families have threshold voltages.